# Assign keyboard shortcut to "Start without debugging"

Tags: ptvs

Python Tools for Visual Studio has the option to [debug a script](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debug%20As%20Script).  How can I assign a keyboard shortcut for this?

Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard does not seem to contain this option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command titles are "Start without Debugging" and "Start with Debugging" (in addition to the context menu, they're also under Project). Consequently, the command names are Project.StartwithoutDebugging and Project.StartwithDebugging - you should be able to find those in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found and tried `Debug.StartWithoutDebugging` which starts the default script for the project, didn't occur to me that `Project.StartwithoutDebugging` would start the script that has focus.  I wonder why they chose the Project menu for something that doesn't operate at project level.

Comment: "They" would be me (well, among other people) in this case. But I can't recall why those commands went into that menu :) Unfortunately, moving them around is hard to sell now that we shipped them this way (since it'll break anything depending on their names, like your shortcut binding).

Comment: Ah well, you solved my problem and PTVS is a great tool, so thank you!

Comment: "They" made it more intuitive in Visual Studio 2015 extension. It is now called `Python.StartwithoutDebugging`.